# What would the mechanism be for intermediate B to Supinidine, and what would by product C be?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organosilicon-compounds

[image]

I have managed to do the mechanism for the first step, but have no clue how 4 equivalents of MeLi are used for the second step of the reaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first eq. of MeLi deprotonates the alcohol. This does not cyclise as it would form a 7-membered ring and that is not strongly favoured.

The subsequent eqs of MeLi remove the methyl carbamate group as described by [Sawyer, et al.](https://doi.org/10.1080/00397918308061971), by consecutive additions of Me to give first the N-acetamide then the amine anion plus acetone. The N anion cyclises onto the chloride to give the product. The final eq. of MeLi adds to the acetone to give Li t-butoxide which gives t-butanol **C** on workup.
[J. S. Sawyer, B. A. Narayanan, *Synth. Comm.*, **1983**, *13*, 135.](https://doi.org/10.1080/00397918308061971)